# Get all associated data for all records of a model type in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I meld together getting all of the  associated data for all of the records of a given model?

I have the following models:

```
User --N:1--> Reservation <--1:N-- Concert
```

So pseudo-code:

```
Reservation belongs_to User
Reservation belongs_to Concert
User has_many Reservations
User has_many Concerts through Reservations
Concert has_many Reservations
Concert has_many Users through Reservations
```

How do I make a single big array of everything?

- I can get all my Reservations via `Reservation.all`
- I can get the User for a particular Reservation via `Reservation.find(25).user`
- I can get the Concert for a particular Reservation via `Reservation.find(25).concert`

But how do I get it for all of them? If I do

```
Reservation.all.each do |res|
   res.user.name+","+res.concert.name+","+res.concert.date # etc.
end
```

Then it will do two new database queries for each reservation as it loops through. For 10 records, it might not matter, but for thousands, it can be very painful. Add to it other associations (e.g. Concert belongs_to venue, User has_one email, etc.)...

Is there any way to say, "Get all of the reservations and the following attached info" so it loads in a single SQL query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to accomplish is called *eager loading*, and can be done using `includes` in `ActiveRecord`. See below:

> **N + 1 queries problem**
>
> Active Record lets you specify in advance all the associations that are going to be loaded. This is possible by specifying the includes method of the Model.find call. With includes, Active Record ensures that all of the specified associations are loaded using the minimum possible number of queries.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

In your example you could use the following:

```
Reservation.all.includes(:user, :concert)
```

---

It is also a good idea to specify the `:inverse_of` option for your `:belongs_to` relations. This optimizes object loading and makes sure that cross-referencing a model will point back to the same object in memory, i.e.:

```
@user == @user.reservations.first.user # true
```

More information available here:

> If you are using a belongs_to on the join model, it is a good idea to set the :inverse_of option on the belongs_to ...

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

In your example:

```
# app/models/reservation.rb

belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :reservations
belongs_to :concert, :inverse_of => :reservations
```

Comment: Ah! I have used eager loading in other ORMs, and knew Rails had eager loading, but I didn't know I could use it on a per-request basis! So if I do `Reservation.all.includes(:user, :concert)` it will do the SELECT and get all of them in a join?

Comment: @deitch: Yes. You can try it out in your console, and compare the SQL being executed between the two.

Comment: Ha! That is exactly what I did. Thanks, Drenmi. Saved me a lot of headache!